# INDEX / MATCH - Array of matches within date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create an array of `Name` matches to populate Column `I` with the following condition:

- Column `G` is within the range of `B2` and `D2`

Similar answers were using this index / match approach:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$5,MATCH(1,(($G$2:$G$5>=$B$2)*($G$2:$G$5<=$D$2)),0))
```

However this only returns one match: `Test D`, which is the last match in the array.

How do I create a running list of matches in Column `I` for every `Name` whose date in Column `G` is within the range of `B2` and `D2`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it looks like your cells holding dates are formatted as Text. There's 31/04/2019 in there.

So make sure that your cells are correctly formatted as Date for Excel to interpret them as Dates so that relevant mathematical calculations are possible.

This solution considers that your list has one header row, as seen above and you are starting your data in row 2. Else a slight manipulation of Index based on ROW() function would be needed.

In Cell I2 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in curly braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$5,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G$5>=$B$2,IF($G$2:$G$5<=$D$2,ROW($F$2:$F$5)-ROW($F$1),9^99),9^99),ROW()-ROW($F$1))),"")
```

Now drag it down along the length of the column, until you get blanks. All your applicable names that fall within the specified date range shall be listed in contiguous cells in that column.

The formula uses INDEX however inside it generates as Array of row numbers in sequence wherever data is applicable and wherever not returns a large number. Combined with SMALL function, INDEX then fetches only the applicable rows in contiguous cells.

[image]

Comment: @ patkim, it seems that our formula breaks when we use =EDATE(B2,C2) to get the End of Range date to be =Today() plus the entered Term month.

Comment: TODAY() will keep on changing everyday. Make sure that all relevant cells are correctly formatted as DATE. Please share a sample screenshot showing for which values it's not working. You can insert a URL in the comments.

Comment: Here is the Google Sheets workbook example I created: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15adNP6hpUDh9w3Ai6C-nrkcMkYl_QfM6TwD9axLED3Q/edit?usp=sharing

You can see it is working if I manually enter in the End of Range date, but the function encounters an error when I use =EDATE() to show all matches that are 3 months from today's date

Comment: In your sheet I put =edate(D2,E2) in F2, number  3 (months) in E2 and now since nothing falls within the range, Columh H returns empty. May be the exact set of values for which you are getting an error and what that error is may help. Also I assume your final working sheet is in MS Excel as per the tags you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: Ok I see, not sure why it was no working in my MS Excel document. But I did notice we used SMALL() to arrange the order of the array to show the earliest dates first, but our formula is returning the most future dates first. Is there a way to change it so the dates closest to today show first?

Comment: The data is returned in the same order in which it appears in Col F. SMALL just knocks off all 9^99 and then INDEX only selects the values in the same order (ROW Manipulation)  in which they appear in the Array returned from Col F. To get the value nearest to Today in that order may need a different solution. Simple workaround could be to sort F-G based on G in Oldest To Newest order.